How do I get the topics used in a ML.NET Latent Dirichlet Allocation?
When using ML.NET to perform a Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) on a sample set of documents I can get the prediction (correlation) between each document and the topics extracted but I cannot get the actual topics extracted by ML.NET LDA.
I tried running the ML.NET LDA GitHub example here:
LatentDirichletAllocation.cs
The above code specifies 3 topics. The results show the prediction (correlation) of each document with each of 3 topics but it does not show what 3 topics were determined by LDA. It just shows prediction 1, 2, 3 for each document. A debugger reveals no way to actually see what 3 topics were determined by the LDA API.
I also tried running this ML.NET sample from GitHub:
ProduceWordBags.cs
It, too, compiles and runs fine but it only produces the words in each document grouped (tokenized) by the specified length of the topics. It does not show what topics are extracted from the set of sample documents.
I was expecting that one of the ML.NET APIs would allow me to see what topics are extracted when using a Latent Dirichlet Allocation against a set of sample documents. None of the ML.NET samples did that as far as I can determine.
I would very much appreciate a clear example of how to extract the actual topics determined by LDA in ML.NET as text strings.
Thank you in advance.

Ultimately, I found an answer which turned out to be a bit convoluted but appears to work. Here is what I did:

I removed creating the Lda Estimator from the preprocessing chain and preprocessed the sample data using that new chain.

I created an Lda Estimator in a separate step.

From the Lda Estimator I created an Lda Transformer.

The Lda Transformer has a method "GetLDADetails" which provides information on the topics extracted from the LDA.

I examined and printed out the information (topics and scores) supplied by "GetLDADetails"


All-in-all somewhat convoluted but it works. It would be nice to have a method attached directly to the Lda Estimator or PredictionEngine which shows what topics have been extracted from the data used to train the model.

I am just exploring this myself, I would very much like to see what you did, my goal is the same as yours i.e. find the topics as well as the % the % on its own is a bit useless. So what I am interested in following and understanding what was the resulting code from your 1 through 5 here.

As far as I can see, having played with this for a day what you need to do with the existing transformer (no need to create an lda estimator in a seperate step). Is then taking your transformer object and doing the following two lines var ldaTransformer = transformer.LastTransformer, then from that ldaTransformer you can var ldaDetails = ldaTransformer.GetDetails(0) this appears to get you the words and the scores the name of the topic is not really gettable because its an abstract thing, but you can find the words and the scores with this. So its simpler than described - but thank you
